# How to center frame in tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, frame

I have a GUI with several Windows. One of the Windows is too big, so had to implement a Scrollbar, which had to be done with a Canvas. This caused, the problem, that the Canvas is never center in the middle of the Window, which automatically has the size of the display.

How Can I center the Canvas in the middle (and top) of the display-Window and still keep the Scrollbar to the right? 
I know that the first frame (frame0) is not really needed, but it makes it easier for me afterwards. 
I updated the script below, so it is able to run as standalone. I know it is not really nice, but it is a pritty much a summary of all my code.

Thanks for your help.

```
from Tkinter import *


class GUI:

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.myParent = parent

        self.frame = Frame(self.myParent, bd = 2, relief = GROOVE, padx = 20, pady = 20)


        self.RWidth=self.frame.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.RHeight=self.frame.winfo_screenheight()
        self.myParent.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (self.RWidth, self.RHeight))  # Make Window fullscreen if no other geometry definition


    def GUI(self):

        self.myParent.title("Transport to Sorting-Point")  # Title of Window

        self.frame0 = Frame(self.myParent)
        self.frame0.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)     
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame0)
        self.vsb = Scrollbar(self.frame0, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set, highlightthickness=0)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        self.frame = Frame(self.canvas, bd = 2, relief = GROOVE, padx = 20, pady = 20)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor = N)
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)

        self.Text = Label(self.frame, text='This is a Text ', justify = LEFT).grid(row=0, column=0)


        self.frame0.mainloop()

    def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all'))


def main():         
    root = Tk()
    myapp = GUI(root)
    myapp.GUI()

    root.option_clear

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your code can't be run. It appears to be a method of some class, but the rest of the class is missing. You also don't show us what GUI is. Without the rest of the code we have to guess as to what other widgets and pack/place/grid options you're using.

Comment: I edited my script, so it can be run alone. I hope you can help me now! Sorry for the bad script before.

Comment: I don't see the problem. When I run your code the canvas fills the whole window, so I don't know what you mean when you say you want to center it.

Comment: Yes, the canvas fills the entire window, but the self.frame is on upper left corner, which I would like to be centered.

Comment: You should clarify your question, because it sounds like you want the canvas centered, but if I understand you correctly now, you want the _contents_ of the canvas centered. Is that right?

Comment: Correct! I will Change the title. To clarify, I thought at the beginning, that the canvas was not centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the width and height of the canvas, simply place the frame in the center of the canvas with a little math:

```
x0 = self.frame.winfo_screenwidth()/2
y0 = self.frame.winfo_screenheight()/2
self.canvas.create_window((x0,y0), window=self.frame, anchor = "center")
```